# Reverse engineer original color given color blended with white

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-reproduction

I've got a color that is some color of purple mixed with white. I would like to create the same color by making a **transparent layer of purple** and then placing a white background underneath.

So for example, this color:

[image]

can be made by placing this transparent color of purple

[image]

over a white background.

If I am given the first color, is there an easy way to reverse engineer what the second color would be? This problem comes from the fact that when I exported a layer in photoshop, I accidentally included the white background several days ago and lost some color information.

Thank you so much!

Comment: hi, thanks but this isn't quite what I'm looking for, since all I know is the resultant color (the first one shown in my post), and the white color.

Comment: I think the duplicate I added is actually the same question. Check out the link to my JSFiddle in the comments below the accepted answer. But it might give you some problems. If the background is just white you need to know the used alpha percentage.

Comment: Ah I see, yes that should solve it, thank you!